# Correct blending mode for r8Unorm texture

Tags: macos, metal, blending

Destination texture and brush textures are `r8Unorm`. What will be correct blending mode in this case?

Brush texture is radial gradient and looks like this:

[image]

On the first draw call it looks correct, but on the next draw calls it becomes full red circle without any gradient.

My current wrong blending settings looks like this:

```
private func createBrushDescriptor(library: MTLLibrary) -> MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor {
    let vertexDescriptor = MTLVertexDescriptor()
    vertexDescriptor.attributes[0].format = .float2
    vertexDescriptor.attributes[0].offset = 0
    vertexDescriptor.attributes[0].bufferIndex = 0

    vertexDescriptor.layouts[0].stride = 2 * MemoryLayout<simd_float1>.size
    vertexDescriptor.layouts[0].stepFunction = .perVertex
    vertexDescriptor.layouts[0].stepRate = 1
    
    let descriptor = MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor()
    descriptor.vertexFunction = library.makeFunction(name: "brush_vertex_function")
    descriptor.vertexDescriptor = vertexDescriptor
    descriptor.fragmentFunction = library.makeFunction(name: "brush_fragment_function")
    descriptor.colorAttachments[0].pixelFormat = .r8Unorm
    
    descriptor.colorAttachments[0].isBlendingEnabled = true
    descriptor.colorAttachments[0].rgbBlendOperation = .add
    descriptor.colorAttachments[0].sourceRGBBlendFactor = .one
    descriptor.colorAttachments[0].destinationRGBBlendFactor = .one
    
    descriptor.depthAttachmentPixelFormat = .invalid
    
    return descriptor
}
```

I draw brush using `MTLPrimitiveType.point` primitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with this configuration:

```
descriptor.colorAttachments[0].isBlendingEnabled = true
descriptor.colorAttachments[0].rgbBlendOperation = .max
descriptor.colorAttachments[0].sourceRGBBlendFactor = .one
descriptor.colorAttachments[0].destinationRGBBlendFactor = .one
```